# Read xml with JAXB

Tags: jaxb

How can I read the below xml with jaxb?

```
       <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='ATCCode' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='ATC'
             rs:basetable='#t1' rs:basecolumn='ATCCode'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='DDD' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='ATC' rs:basetable='#t1'
             rs:basecolumn='DDD'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='20'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='UnitType' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='ATC'
             rs:basetable='#t1' rs:basecolumn='UnitType'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='255'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='AdmCode' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='ATC'
             rs:basetable='#t1' rs:basecolumn='AdmCode'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='255'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='DDDComment' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='ATC'
             rs:basetable='#t1' rs:basecolumn='DDDComment'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='255'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AA01' DDD='1.1' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O' DDDComment='0.5 mg Fluoride'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AA03' DDD='1.1' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB02' DDD='60' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB03' DDD='30' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB04' DDD='40' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB05' DDD='0.18' UnitType='g' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB06' DDD='3' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB07' DDD='80' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB09' DDD='0.2' UnitType='g' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB10' DDD='20' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A01AB23' DDD='1' UnitType='mg' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A02AA04' DDD='3' UnitType='g' AdmCode='O'/>
    <z:row ATCCode='A02AB02' DDD='5' UnitType='g' AdmCode='O'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Java model class:-

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "xml")   
    public class Xml{
        @XmlElement 
        private List<Data> data;

    }
```

And then load it

```
private Xml unmarshall() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Xml.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();        
    return (Xml) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
}
```

But I always get the data field as null. So my question is what would be the right model for this type of xml?

Comment: Any specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Well first, though your list is called `data`, according to your schema, the Elements inside of it are of type `raw`. Therefore you also need to model `raw` in java.

Second, the list would be your element *wrapper*. To specifiy that you can use the Annotation `XmlElementWrapper`.

And finally, your java class should probably be called `Data` not Xml!

Your Class would then look like the following:

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data{

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="rows")
    @XmlElement(name="row")
    private List<Row> rows;

    // Getters and Setters!!

}
```

Basically the annotation `XmlElementWrapper` tells JAXB that this field is a collection and the attribute `name` specifies the Xml Element it maps to. While the xml tag of elements of that collection are specified by the `name` attribute of the `XmlElement` annotation.

For a complete example (also the source of my snippet) check: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Of course, alternatively, you could try generate java classes from the schema using **xjc**